# SSH Slow to Connect on IPV6

Tags: ssh, ipv6

Firstly I've looked at all the existing answers and none have fixed my problems (UseDNS etc.) The problem is when I try to connect to my VPS with SSH (Putty is the same) there is a long delay (~1+ minutes) about 50% of the time. Using `ssh -vvv` I found where it hangs:

```
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "mydomain.ca" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to mydomain.ca [0:0:0:0::0] port 22.
<hangs right here>
debug1: connect to address 0:0:0:0::0 port 22: Resource temporarily unavailable
debug1: Connecting to mydomain.ca [1.1.1.1] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
```

It hangs then gives the Resource temporarily unavailable, at which point it tries IPv4 and connects right away.

I tried using the `-4` paramter to force IPv4 and it does force IPv4 but oddly the problem remains, so I'm thinking this problem lies deeper than SSHD. I'm basically just using whatever network configuration my host (OVH) provided when the VPS was set up, but I wanted to ask here before I go and ask them about it. The server is running Debian 8 Jessie.

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://askubuntu.com/questions/344863/ssh-new-connection-begins-to-hang-not-reject-or-terminate-after-a-day-or-so-on

Comment: I had been using GoDaddy for DNS when this was slow and changed to a different domain provider and stopped having the problem. Now I'm back with GoDaddy and the problem is there again! I don't know how to explain it though.